# print highest value from text file

Tags: python-3.x

[image: Question - print highest spent the amount of id in June 2017]

**data.txt**

```
May-2017-120-245.50
Jun-2017-124-21.50
Jun-2017-110-34.00
Jun-2017-120-200.00
Jul-2017-124-546.50
Jul-2017-110-1500.00
Jun-2017-124-245.50
```

**code :**

```
info = {}
with open('/home/bista/Desktop/data.txt') as input_file:
  for line in input_file:
    month,year, emp_id, bill_amount = (item.strip() for item in line.split('-', 4))
    month = dict(zip(('month','month'),map(str, month.split('/'))))
    info[id] = dict(zip(('month','emp_id','bill_amount'),(month,emp_id, bill_amount)))
    # print(info)
    create_new_dict = {}
    for id, record in info.items():
        # print(record)
        if record['month']['month'] == 'Jun':
          new= {record['emp_id']:{'emp_id':record['emp_id'],'bill_amount':record['bill_amount']}}
          # print(new)
          create_new_dict.update(new)
          # print("s",create_new_dict)
          max = 0.0
          for key,value in create_new_dict.items():
            # print(max)
            if float(value['bill_amount']) > max:
              max =float(value['bill_amount'])
              # print("emp_id:",value['emp_id'])
          print("emp_id:",value['emp_id'])
```

**Question:**

print results:

```
root@bista:/home/bista/Desktop# python3 get.py 
emp_id: 124
emp_id: 110
emp_id: 120
emp_id: 124
```

but result should be emp_id: 124

Comment: your print is inside your `for` loop so it will print the id for every record in June

Comment: if I use outside for loop, I am getting this "NameError: name 'value' is not defined"

Comment: because you're also not printing the max you're just printing each id ...